# Servlet Ajax global exception handling

Tags: jquery, servlets, error-handling

I have a global handler for my AJAX calls

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             //do something 
    }
});
```

And in case of an error my servlet filter  sends a specifc error

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

    if(somethingwrong()) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "unavailableimage");    
    }
}
```

Would you recommend to do something like

```
$.ajaxError({
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (xhr.status == 408) {
            //doSomething
        }
        else if xhr.responseText.contains("unavailableimage"){
            //doSomething
        }
    }
});
```

Because I think the responseText is different in every browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The response body is available by `xhr.responseText`.

However, the [`HttpServletResponse#sendError()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) ( <-- click the link to read the Javadoc yourself) will use the servletcontainer's default error page template or your custom error page template as you've definied in `web.xml`. This is a HTML document which you thus have to parse yourself.

As per your comment on the other answer, you seem to be using Tomcat and retrieving its default error page; the message is available as first `<u>` element of the second `<p>`. So this should do:

```
var errorMessage = $(xhr.responseText).filter('p:eq(1)').find('u').text();

if (errorMessage == 'unavailableimage') {
    // ...
}
```

You only need to keep in mind that you're this way tight coupled to the markup of the (default) error page. Better is to not use `HttpServletResponse#sendError()`, but just set the status by [`HttpServletResponse#setStatus()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int%29) ( <-- yes, click it to read javadoc, the answer was in there) and write the error message to the response body yourself:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
response.getWriter().write("unavailableimage");
```

This way the `xhr.responseText` is exactly `unavailableimage`.

```
if (xhr.responseText == 'unavailableimage') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much BalusC this was exactly what i was looking for. You saved the day :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my projects, I'm using this function for debugging ajax :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        error:function(x,e){
            if(x.status==0){
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            }else if(x.status==404){
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            }else if(x.status==500){
                alert('Internal Server Error.\n'+x.responseText););
            }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            }else if(e=='timeout'){
                alert('Request Time out.');
            }else {
                alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

so with your code, you can test if the `x.responseText` contains 'unavailableimage', but testing it by error code and error message is better ;)

Another way to get only the response error message is to use : `var responseText = $.httpData(xhr)` depending of your version of JQuery (< 1.5.2)

Or using json : `var responseText = $.parseJSON(x.responseText);`

Comment: Thank you very much for the anwser. My problem now is, that the responseText is something like --> <html>.... <apache tomcat...> Internal Server error (unavilableimage). Would you just test if the error contains my "unavilableimage"

Comment: did you alert the 'e' variable too ? to see what it displays. Let me know :) Try alerting 'x.statusText' too.

Comment: They both e and x.statusText got 'error' But I could do a contain search in responseText

Comment: :) thanks but i am using jQuery 1.6. My problem was more of a servlet problem then a jQuery problem. I can now perfectly work with x.responseText thanks again for your help

Comment: I'm glad it has helped you ;)